# Return Foreign Key Data on Get All Call

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have my unit of measure in the database, when you save a unit, you save the name, id, tenant Id and more to the table, then UnitSize get saved to its own table UnitOfMeasureSize. It shares the UnitOFMeasureId and I need to figure out how to get the the UnitSize back and display it with the UOM name on the interface. I read up on entities and feel like i have it right so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

here is my dropdown
[image: Accordion dropdown]

```
namespace Mudman.Data.Entities
{   
     [Table("UnitOfMeasure")]
    public class UnitOfMeasure : IEntityBase, IAuditBase
     {
    [Key]
    [Column("UnitOfMeasureId")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("TenantId")]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<UnitOfMeasureSize> UnitSize { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string CreateUserId { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string UpdateUserId { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
namespace Mudman.Data.Entities
  {
     [Table("UnitOfMeasureSize")]
     public class UnitOfMeasureSize : IEntityBase, IAuditBase
    {
    [Key]
    [Column("UnitOfMeasureSize")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("TenantId")]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("UnitOfMeasureId")]
    public string UnitOfMeasureId { get; set; }
    public virtual UnitOfMeasure UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UnitSize { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string CreateUserId { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string UpdateUserId { get; set; }


   }
}

     public async Task<IEnumerable<UnitOfMeasureViewModel>> GetAllAsync()
 {
     var result = await _unitOfMeasureRepo.FindByAsync(uom => uom.TenantId == TenantId);
     result.OrderBy(r => r.Name);
     
     return _mapper.Map<List<UnitOfMeasure>, List<UnitOfMeasureViewModel>>(result.ToList());
 }
```

Here is how I am trying to grab the Unit Sizes in my AdminStore

```
   public getUnitSizes(unitOfMeasureId: string) {

     return this.api.get(`/${unitOfMeasureId}/UnitSize`)
        .then(
            (data: any) => data,
            (error: any) => {throw error;}
        );
 }



public getUnitSizes = async (unitOfMeasureId: string) => {
    const list: any[] = await this.adminAPI.getUnitSizes(unitOfMeasureId);

    runInAction(() => {
        this.unitSizes = list;
    });

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Navigation Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) in Entity Framework

Comment: Yeah i have, thats where I set up my entities but I'm not getting anything back. I added my entities to the code above

Comment: Are you calling `.Include(uom => uom.UnitSize)` in your repository?

Comment: Entity Framework Core doesn't do lazy loading anymore. You have to explicitly tell it to include navigation properties when you query. As an aside, this means you don't need to mark all the navigation properties as `virtual`

Comment: I have not! Just looked into it a bit, how does this look?

  `public IQueryable<UnitOfMeasure> GetAllCategorys() {return context.UnitOfMeasure Include(uom => uom.UnitSize); } }`

Comment: Yes, that's what I imagined was missing. By the way, AutoMapper is capable of working directly with Entity Framework. If you use the [Queryable extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html), AutoMapper will request the fields in your view model from the matching tables